# Weak form of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on closed manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, finite-element-method

Suppose we are dealing with diffusion over a boundaryless manifold $M$ (for simplicity let's say it's a surface). In that case, we have
\begin{align}
\int_M W \Delta U \mathrm{d} x & = -\int_M \nabla W \cdot \nabla U \mathrm{d} x,
\end{align}
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator and $\nabla$ the surface gradient.
What I have seen plenty of times in papers is that people simply take this identity and use it over a non-smooth surface $M^*$ that approximates $M$, for example via tessellation to derive a system of equations for a finite-element approximation. The problem is that on non-smooth surfaces the above identity is not applicable.
Here is what I believe happens: I believe that you should carry out the integral over all triangles $T_i$ that make up $\mathcal{M}^*$
\begin{align}
\int_{M^*} W \Delta U \mathrm{d} x & = \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{T_i} W \Delta U \mathrm{d} x \nonumber \\
& = -\int_{M^*} \nabla W \cdot \nabla U \mathrm{d} x + \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{\partial T_i} W \nabla U \cdot \mathbf{N}_{\partial T_i} \mathrm{d} \Gamma.
\end{align}
So essentially they have weakly imposed that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{\partial T_i} W \nabla U \cdot \mathbf{N}_{\partial T_i} \mathrm{d} \Gamma = 0.
\end{align}
So I believe that the solutions of the FEM-approach weakly satisfy
\begin{align}
\nabla U \cdot \mathbf{N}_{\partial T_i^j}  = - \nabla U \cdot \mathbf{N}_{\partial T_k^l},
\end{align}
whenever $\partial T_i^j$ and $\partial T_k^l$ overlap on $M^*$ (which any strong solution automatically satisfies).
Is this correct ? And if so, can someone give a rigorous proof or at least a reference to a source where this is explained ?
Thanks in advance.